# AWS Javascript SDK - startMedicalTranscriptionJob not support mic device

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am a newbie in using AWS JavaScript SDK. I am trying to create an HTML page like the UI of Amazon Transcribe Medical - Real-time transcription ([link](https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/home?region=us-east-2#realTimeMedicalTranscription)). The Real-time transcription works fine with microphone device. I mean it converts the speech data (input the audio from mic device) to text in real-time, Works fine and I really impressed and decided to create a UI like below image.

[image]

I read the documentation of the AWS JavaScript SDK in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/TranscribeService.html#startMedicalTranscriptionJob-property

[image]

but there is confusion about the input audio input parameter (`MediaFileUri` parameter), in the documentation of the above method it's not allowed to capture the audio from the mic device (or I can't find any input parameter for mic devices), it's only possible to input audio files from amazon bucket.

[image: z]

So how I create a UI like Amazon real-time transcription using this method? Any advice for acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transcribe medical support two modes: streaming and batch. The SDK you use is batch API, as in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/TranscribeService.html#startMedicalTranscriptionJob-property

Javascript SDK for transcribe medical streaming is not yet released. But you can implement your own WebSocket client.

This is tech document about Transcribe medical streaming WebSocket protocol: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/websocket-med.html

For implementation in javascript, please refer to sample code: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-transcribe-medical-demo/blob/master/src/transcribe/TranscriptionWindow.js#L138-L160